# Debugging yields incorrect syntax near keyword 'where'

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following function that I am trying to run that joins a `product` table and a `productcategory` table and return the results. The debugger, when exception is thrown, displays the query string and I have tried running the query string in my test mysql database and it works.

The `CategorizedProduct` is a model. I have checked and made sure that all the fields in the `select` list match the fields in the model.

I cannot find where the error is.

```
public static List<CategorizedProduct> GetAllCategorizedProducts(string category)
{
    using (var conn = Sql.GetConnection())
    {
        string queryString = "select ProductID,ProductName,ProductType,ProductCategory,CategoryName,Unit,PricePerUnit,IsAvailable,NumberOfUnits,RemainingUnits,WeightPerUnit" +
            " from product inner join productcategory where product.ProductCategory = productcategory.CategoryID and CategoryName = \'" + category + "\' order by ProductType;";
        return conn.Query<CategorizedProduct>(queryString).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: A `join` should be followed by an `on` clause (although I think this is optional in MySQL).

Comment: @GordonLinoff you do need to specify what you are joining on :)

Comment: @czchlong . . . Are you sure the database is MySQL?  Or, perhaps, you have an intermediate layer such as an ODBC driver that checks the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version instead:

```
select ProductID, ProductName, ProductType, ProductCategory,
       CategoryName, Unit, PricePerUnit, IsAvailable, NumberOfUnits,
       RemainingUnits, WeightPerUnit
from product inner join
     productcategory 
     on product.ProductCategory = productcategory.CategoryID 
where CategoryName = \'" + category + "\'
order by ProductType;
```

I do think that the `on` is optional in MySQL after `join`, but this might fix your problem.  The `on` is required by any other database (and I think if you have certain ANSI settings on in MySQL).